pfSense не устанавливается в VirtualBox
pfSense не устанавливается, в конце предлагает сделать ребут и в итоге запускает установку заново. При такой же установке на VMware все устанавливалось без проблем.


Я, так понимаю, pf устанавливается нормально, но, в приоритете загрузки виртуалки, жёсткий диск стоит последний и до него загрузка не доходит, начинается загрузка с виртуального привода.
